# Can't install needed python3-scope-harness for Ubuntu Scopes dev in Go

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch, scopes, golang

At https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/scopes/tutorials/developing-scopes-go/ it tells me to run

> sudo apt-get install unity-scope-tool golang git bzr python3-scope-harness mercurial

But I receive the error:

> E: Package 'python3-scope-harness' has no installation candidate

(Pastie: http://pastebin.com/f5fYSUfr)

According to http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty-backports&keywords=python3-scope-harness , python3-scope-harness has *not* been backported to Trusty (14.04).  So, I'm really not sure how to install it.

And yes, I've already run

> sudo apt-get update

How should I proceed?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Scope development isn't supported in Go *on Ubuntu 14.04*.  I'm now dev'ing in Ubuntu 15.10, and all is well!

Answer (score 0):

Failed attempt: I just upgraded to the latest Ubuntu SDK

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa

then

> sudo apt update && sudo apt install ubuntu-sdk

as instructed by https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-sdk/installing-the-sdk/ .  *Then* I ran

> sudo apt-get install unity-scope-tool golang git bzr python3-scope-harness mercurial

...but it still can't find `python3-scope-harness` :-\